# How to get rid of \n, commas and brackets?

Tags: python, file, random

Here is my code:

```
import random
a = open("10.txt", "r")
#print (a.read())
grid1 = a.readlines()
random.shuffle(grid1) 
row1 = grid1[1].rstrip(), grid1[2].rstrip(), grid1[3].rstrip()
row2 = grid1[4].rstrip(), grid1[5].rstrip(), grid1[6].rstrip()
row3 = grid1[7].rstrip(), grid1[8].rstrip(), grid1[9].rstrip()
print (row1)
print (row2)
print (row3)
```

But it comes out as:

```
('GHOST', 'TOOTH', 'BROWN')
('ABOUT', 'SMOKE', 'FUNNY')
('NIGHT', 'CAMEL', 'PRICE')
```

I would like it without the brackets, commas, speech marks, etc.

Comment: You realise that those characters are part of Python's syntax, right? You are creating three `tuple` objects, each of which contains three `string` objects - the parentheses `()` and commas `,` are for the tuple, the quote marks `'` are for the strings.

Comment: Use `+` to concatenate strings. `grid1[1].rstrip() + grid1[2].rstrip()` or use formatting `'{} {} {}'.format(grid1[1].rstrip(), grid1[2].rstrip(), grid1[3].rstrip())` or you can use join on tuples `' '.join(row1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `print(''.join(row1))` and so on

Comment: Thanks worked and helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Or don't even bother making rows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import random

grid = [
'GHOST', 'TOOTH', 'BROWN',
'ABOUT', 'SMOKE', 'FUNNY',
'NIGHT', 'CAMEL', 'PRICE']

print grid

random.shuffle(grid)

print ''.join(["%s%s" % (word, ' ' if i % 3 else '\n') for i, word in enumerate(grid, 1)])
```

**typical output**

```
['GHOST', 'TOOTH', 'BROWN', 'ABOUT', 'SMOKE', 'FUNNY', 'NIGHT', 'CAMEL', 'PRICE']
TOOTH PRICE CAMEL
ABOUT NIGHT SMOKE
BROWN GHOST FUNNY
```

(plus an extra blank line)

Answer (score 0):

Since row1 is a tuple python prints it with the tuple syntax.  Ju

```
row1 = ('GHOST', 'TOOTH', 'BROWN')
row2 = ('ABOUT', 'SMOKE', 'FUNNY')
row3 = ('NIGHT', 'CAMEL', 'PRICE')

for row in [row1, row2, row3]:
    for x in row:
         print x,
    print
```